# Removing empty bytes from List<byte>

Tags: c#, list, arrays

How do I delete empty bytes from a `List<byte>`?

For example I got a list with a size of `[5]`.

```
[0] = 5
[1] = 3
[2] = 0
[3] = 0
[4] = 17
```

At this example I want to delete `byte` with index: 2 and 3.

The Items in the list change every second. So the next time the list could be filled with something like:

```
[0] = 0
[1] = 2
[2] = 3
[3] = 4
[4] = 0
```

Comment: How certain are you that those aren't *meaningful* 0 values?

Comment: Interesting that the only answer that technically responded to the request "Now I want to delete byte with index: 2 and 3." was deleted.

Comment: @ColinMackay I re-instated it :) I first thought by looking at the other answers that the OP was looking to simply remove any values which are 0. However, like Jon's comment suggests the value of the item may not necessarily dictate that it should be deleted (i.e. there might be a 0 value item which the OP *does* want to keep).

Comment: If the items in the list change every second, is this in another thread? If so then List<byte> may not be suitable because if you are removing items while another thread is adding/updating items you are likely to get issues. Consider one of the Concurrent collections if that is the case.

Comment: I think he just means that he'll be getting new data each time, but clarification is needed!

Comment: No, just when the user interacts with the application it could change to a list with completely different values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's something like

```
myList.RemoveAll(b => b == 0);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
bytes.RemoveAll(x => x == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using **[List.RemoveAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)** method?

> Removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the
>   specified predicate.

```
YourList.RemoveAll(n => n == 0);
```

For example;

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(){5, 3, 0, 0, 17};
list.RemoveAll(n => n == 0);

foreach (var i in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Output will be;

```
5
3
17
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/MVyNOQ)**.